# why tensorflow restore from ckpt the same variable with different values

Tags: tensorflow

when I use tensorflow restore, run the code as follows, Each run will produce different results.

```
import tensorflow as tf

ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state("./models/")
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path + '.meta')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    weights = sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('output_weights/obj_w:0'))
    print(weights[0])
```

Comment: Do you refer to the weights coming up different after loading several times exactly the same ckpt file? Or are you training the model several times and loading the ckpt files for the newly trained models? On the second case, it's plausible that the weights come up different. On the first not.

Comment: the weights coming up different after loading several times, so I'm confused about that.